# Hit Counter PHP, TXT, Image and Imagick

Tags: php, .htaccess, imagick, hitcounter

Some days Ago I started to create a SaaS Hit counter System, I founded some problems but solved, in the last answer about this I just talked about the problem so no codes have been posted with the solution...

Well, I have 95% created but I need to run the PHP file which contain the script inside the image, I tried to insert some rules inside Htaccess file but got no lucky, Below is the code for who wants to help and use ;)

```
$number = trim(file_get_contents('visitas.txt'));//for Example: 92

$file = 'visitas.txt'; 
$views = file_get_contents ($file); 
$fdata = intval($views)+1; 
file_put_contents($file, $fdata);

$sources = str_split($number);
array_walk($sources,function(&$item) {$item .= '.png';});



$stack = new Imagick();
foreach( $sources as $source ) {
    $stack->addImage(new Imagick($source));
}

$montage = $stack->montageImage(new ImagickDraw(), '10x1', '40x33', 0, '0');
$montage->writeImage('output.gif');

?>

<img src="output.gif" />
```

So each refresh in the page which contains this script, one view summ the counter, everything perfect right? nop.. because I need to embed the output.gif in another domains and need to execute the script each time the .gif get reloaded

So I tried to put this code in my Htaccess but just did an error 500 =/

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +Indexes
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^output.gif$ output.php[R=301,L]
```

Heres a print of the Counter working:

[image: counter]

Someone knows how can I run my .gif as php?

Comment: What **exactly** is not working with the given code? Is this a PHP problem, a problem with the htaccess, or with imagick?

Comment: Everything working with the code, but i need to execute the code when the embed output.gif has loaded, currently I need to access the output.php

Comment: I need to make the php code run just embeding the <img src="output.gif" /> to the pages

Comment: Wow why someone unvoted this?

Comment: _"but just did an error 500"_ - the first thing you should always do when you get a 500, is check the server error log.

Comment: This should probably not be an external redirect, but an internal rewrite only, to begin with.

Comment: Thats not fair unvote this answer... I put all code created with all explanation, and just asking how to run the php and gif, thats unfair....

Comment: You can seperate the image generation, in the new file replace ``writeImage()`` with a method that outputs base64 data of the image, then in the display page use ``<img src="http://full-url/generator.php" />``

Comment: Ok so how could I do the right redirect? could  you help me or its more easy unvote the question did for a person got days searching for solutions and give all the code for who wants to use...

Comment: Please share more details. If everything is working, what's the problem? What do you mean by "execute the code when the embed output.gif has loaded"?

Comment: @NicoHaase I cant embed the counter with php.file, I need to use a .gif file to embed in another domains right? Something like: <img src="output.gif" />, but this file is static, so I need to run the php code (which contains the script to sum) as .gif

Comment: "I cant embed the counter with php.file" - why can't you do that? Is there anything not working when using `<img src="counter.php">` which would print the image directly, without writing it to a file first?

Comment: Hey @Sami could you show me an example? I still need to use the .gif file to embed in another domains

Comment: And have you tried to resolve this in any kind? Using **two** HTTP calls (one to increment the counter, one to fetch the generated image) sounds strange to me. Also, only because everyone else uses `.gif` does not mean that you also have to. Also, you could also use `.gif` with a `RewriteRule`

Comment: yes I want to use .gif with rewrite rule, could you explain to me how to do that? please

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer.

Comment: Right, Thanks for your kind words @Yunnosch , I tried to accept my own answer but said I can in 2 days

Comment: not sure if you notice, such counter mechanism is unreliable. Imagine two visitors access your page at the same time... in short, don't use a file to save the count.

Comment: Tested and everything worked, simultaneos access. I dont want to use mysql because it will consume much memory from the server, Imagine 500 sites using the counter, with 10 access simultaneos in each site... With PHP and TXT its only HTTP request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone who wants to use, I did this:

- Add this rules to my root htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/output.gif$ /output.php [L]
```

- Add this codes to output.php

```
$montage->setImageFormat('gif');
header("Content-Type: image/gif");
echo $montage->getImageBlob();
```

And removed:

```
$montage->writeImage('output.gif');
```